# Can the Microsoft Virtual PC .vhd be "activated" instead of expiring?

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I usually use the Virtual PC `.vhd` from  http://www.Microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575  together with Windows 7's Virtual PC to emulate an XP machine, so as to run any XP software or do software testing with Internet Explorer 7 or Internet Explorer 8 (for browser compatibility testing).

But often, I may want to keep the image and I can actually use an older serial number of Windows XP I had to activate it (or else the image may expire within a couple of months), but if I follow the method of activation [here](http://support.Microsoft.com/kb/307890) it will say the Windows XP is already activated and so there is no way to let the `.vhd` not expire.  Is there a way to make it not expire?

(I often use the newest `.vhd` because those are the most updated images and also I don't need to waste 30 to 45 minutes installing Windows XP from a CD and then run all the SP2 and SP3 updates, especially if I need to do it at the work machine, and then at home on the desktop, and then on the notebook).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  These images are now available on http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/ and the license there explicitly forbids activating the image.  When it expires you download a new image which has its timer reset, or create a snapshot before using to rollback to.

> 3. NO ACTIVATION.  To prevent its unlicensed use, the software contains activation enforcement technology.  Because the software is
>      licensed for testing use only, you are not licensed to activate the
>      software for any purpose even if it prompts you to do so.

http://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/release_notes_license_terms_1_5_15.pdf